Expression not in GROUP BY clause with only_full_group_by enabled
I'm working on a project where I have a query that retrieves products from a MySQL database. However, I keep encountering the following error:

Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
nonaggregated column 'peplistings.pep_browse_com_prods.com_id' which
is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

SELECT com_id,product_id,image,product_name 
FROM pep_browse_com_prods 
WHERE MATCH (company_name, product_name) AGAINST ('>charcoal*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND status = 0 
AND display = 0 
AND sub_cat_id IN (1955,1672,2166,2120,2120,2120,1466,1672,1672,1672,2146,189,1805,187,187,1586,703,2120,703,1798,1585,1846,1846,1846,1058,1028,22,1106,1106) 
AND status='0' 
AND display='0' 
GROUP BY sub_cat_id 
LIMIT 0,10

Can anyone help me understand:

Why this error occurs?
How can I fix this query to work with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode?


It seem the query and the error message don't match? There is no table peplistings in the query. Anyway, can you please put some effort in making your question easier to read by using a few of the many options the editor here has to properly format it?

@KIKOSoftware peplistings appears to be the database name here.

@C3roe Ah, yes, that would make sense. I missed the dot in pep_browse_com_prods.com_id.

i get this error when i try to change sql mode ,
Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
